# Starting app on PC start-up in Symbian S60

Tags: java, symbian, java-me

How do I make my application come at start-up? I'm using a Nokia N97 phone emulator on my PC. I'm developing using Java for Symbian S60 5th edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java, as far as I know, you can't, at least not directly. With C++ you can use the [Startup List Management API](http://developer.symbian.org/main/documentation/reference/s3/pdk/specs/guides/Startup_list_Management_API_Specification/Startup_list_Management_API_Specification.html). It *might* be possible to write a C++ shim that launches your Java app, but I don't think I've ever seen that.

Answer (score 0):

On S40 you can auto-start midlets with [Nokia-MIDlet-auto-start](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-C5D3E0F5-72B9-4EE7-8BA7-20DE4A538FB8.html). 
For a lot of application 'auto-start'-like behaviour can be achieved with the Push Registry. I presume you have explored this as a possibility?

Comment: Care to elaborate on what isn't working? i.e. S40/S60, Nokia-MIDlet-auto-start, Push Registry? How is it not working?